# Preflight request in VueJS with axios

Tags: javascript, http-headers, cors, axios, preflight

I am a bit stuck with getting a response from the meetup API. The error I am getting:

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.`

Here's my code:

```
var config = {'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization'}

axios.get(`https://api.meetup.com/self/calendar?&sign=true&photo-host=public&page=20`, {headers: config})
.then(response => {
  console.log(response.data)
  this.posts = response.data
})
.catch(e => {
  this.errors.push(e)
})
```

I've read a little bit on CORS here [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) but all my attempts in getting this to work have failed.

Can any of you shed some light on this?

Thanks,

Manu

Comment: I believe for this API you have to setup OAuth first: 
As per: https://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I got this working now. Both @FailedUnitTest and @Manav Mandal suggestions are worth considering. However, instead of using **OAuth** you can use an **API key** - which I found easier. Also, my proxy is my **expressJS** server.

On the server side you would have something along the following lines:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var axios = require('axios');

// meetup API
var instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.meetup.com/'
});

app.get('/anything', function(req, res) {
  const apiKey = 'yourKey';
  const isSigned = 'true';
  const photoHost = 'public';
  const pageCount = '20';
  const url = '/self/calendar?' + 'key=' + apiKey + '&sign=' + isSigned 
+ '&photo-host=' + photoHost + '&page=' + pageCount + '';

  instance.get(url)
  .then(response => {
    return res.send(response.data);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    return e;
  })
});
```

And the client side:

```
data () {
  return {
    cards: [],
    errors: []
  };
},
created () {
  axios.get('/anything')
  .then(response => {
    this.cards = response.data;
  })
  .catch(e => {
    this.errors.push(e);
  });
}
```

Make sure both your server and your client run over the **same** port.

Regards,

Manu

Comment: please accept your answer so that it's obvious that the issue was sovled and a solution is available

Answer (score 1):

your api is not served on same host. either use reverse proxy like nginx or use [cors toggle extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-toggle/jioikioepegflmdnbocfhgmpmopmjkim?hl=en).